# Will BIOS UUID be the same when windows OS is cloned?

Tags: windows, uuid

When an operating system is imaged and deployed on another machine, will both the systems have same UUID's?

I've read that UUID is set by motherboard vendor and will change when the BIOS settings get changed.

Answer (score 2):

It should be pretty easy to just clone a machine and check the UUID using the methods in this article:

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Deploying-Windows-7-Part18.html

Win32_ComputerSystemProduct class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394105.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experienced, the BIOS UUID is still UNIQUE. I have clone PC here and BIOS UUID are UNIQUE.

BTW, I'm using windows. To check just type in command prompt below:

```
C:\> wmic
wmic:root\cli> csproduct
```

And will display the UUID.